# Returning a calculated value in an OOP

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to object oriented programming so I am not sure how to return the results of this calculation in a string. I am looking for an output like this:

The credit rating of John is 187.

My problem is that the credit doesn't seem to be calculated or isn't associated with the object. Should I be returning some value from the the calcCredit method?

```
public class Person
{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private double rating;

public Person(String name, int age)
{
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(int age)
{
    this.age = age;
}

public void calcCredit()
{
    //credit calculation would go here, for my purpose a static number right now.
    rating = 500;

}

//method to returns the status
public String findStatus()
{
   //return my desired output
}
```

---

```
public class CreditDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
        String n = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the age: ");
        int a = keyboard.nextInt();

        Person user = new Person(n, a);

        //how do I call findStatus to get the credit associated with the user?
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a *getter* method to obtain data from a class. Also, another alternative would be to calculate the relevant data and return it instantly. Here's an example based on your `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    //current fields
    public double getCredit() {
        double credit = ...; //calculations here
        //return the value of this variable to clients
        return credit;
    }
}
```

Then, in your client code, call to this method and use the data:

```
public class CreditDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
        String n = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the age: ");
        int a = keyboard.nextInt();

        Person user = new Person(n, a);
        //how do I call findStatus to get the credit associated with the user?
        double credit = user.getCredit();
        System.out.println("Credit for " + user.getName() + " is: " + credit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this your calcCredit() method:

```
public int calcCredit()
{
    int credit = 500;
    //Do some more calculations on credit here

    return credit;
}
```

Implement it like this:

```
Person user = new Person(n, a);

String status = user.findStatus();
int credit = user.calcCredit();

System.out.println("This person's status is " + status);
System.out.println("Their credit is " + credit);
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to initialize the variables in the constructor with the parameters.

As for your question, you could define the findStatus() method as follows,

```
public String findStatus() {
    return "The credit rating of " + name + " is " + rating;
}
```

And in the main method you could call the following method to print the results,

```
System.out.println(user.findStatus());
```

Since you have set methods for name and age, perhaps it would also be a good idea to also define 'get' methods for those specific properties of a person, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have created a Person, you should next calculate his credit rating. To do this, call

```
user.calcCredit();
```

Then you need to print out his status. You can do this as:

```
System.out.println("The credit rating of John is " + user.getStatus());
```

to get your credit, create a public method in class Person:

```
public int getCredit() {
    return this.credit;
}
```

And then you can call user.getCredit() in your main method to print the value.